# What is the reason behind the existence of those many God representations?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vedas, parvati

God is represented in many ways with many names and symbols. Like Shiva, Vishnu, Krishna, Sun, Moon etc. However, the Supreme Being is still only one because the energy is inseparable.

Is the reason behind these many gods like Lord Vishnu, Goddess Lakshmi, Lord Shiva, Goddess Parvathi, Ganesha, Karthikeya, Lord Bramha, Goddess Saraswati is giving a feeling of family to us? Like Lord Shiva is the father, Lord Vishnu is maternal uncle, Goddess Parvathi is mother, Ganesha is our elder brother, Karthikeya is our younger brother etc. Feeling of such fills a lot of courage, because we've got a POWERFUL family.

But what did Vedas and Lord Krishna tell about these many forms of the god?

Comment: the reason is, not every individual's mind is the same. This is the great multiplicity of creation. Thus each individual has affinity to a certain aspect of the Supreme. For example, some may be attracted to God as their father, some attracted to God as their mother, some as their Master, some as their Lover. God, in His infinite Love for us, comes to us, in the form that we pray to Him. Thus to a Shaivite, He appears as Lord Shiva, to a Vaishnavite He appears as Lord Vishnu and so on. The essence is One. This is advaitist thought.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3291/124)

Answer (score 0):

One of the common themes echoed in the vedas and repeatedly told by Ramakrishna paramahamsa and Swami vivekananda and other advaitins is:

> Ekam Sat viprah Bahuda vadanti
>   
> [the truth is one which the wise call by many names]

Eg:It is very difficult for a very mild mannered/soft person to worship a fiery deity like Aghora Veerabhadra,hence sages have prescribed different forms for easier worship and through that worship our mind becomes pure and sees God's true form