# What Is Deva Raja/King of Devas (Indra) a person or a position?

Tags: vedas, puranas, vedanta, indra

I know **Indra** is King of gods so he is called **Dev Raja**.

But My Question is :

**

> Is Indra a Position or Name or a Person's Name ?

**

Thank You

Comment: Indra is a position it can be used in a general
sense for a leader, either of
devatas or asuras 

For more info about it follow the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra

Comment: See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2017/2995) to [What made Indra the king of Svargalok?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2016/2995)